# Restoring iPhone contacts from backup immediately undoes itself

Tags: iphone, backup, contacts

By accident, I deleted most of my contacts on my iPhone. They were also on another device, and were deleted from that one as well when they were deleted off of the iPhone. I restored the iPhone from a backup and they appeared for a minute…then disappeared again. I tried to restore it from the backup again and the same thing happened.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is it possible that you're syncing with something where the contacts are deleted? If so, you will need to disable syncing and see how you can restore your contacts in that place as well.

Comment: @Vlad you should put that as an answer.

Comment: @LoïcWolff - I promised I'd try to not put questions in my answers.

Comment: See if the same thing happens after you disable contact syncing in the settings for iCloud. I'll bet it's an iCloud issue.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that, after restore, you are syncing your iPhone with some source where the contacts have been deleted as well. If so, you will need to stop syncing and/or restore the contacts in that place as well.

Answer (score 0):

There are some apps that allow you to extract the contacts from the iOS backup and to restore it on your idevice like ibackupbot or maybe one of these apps.

Hope it helps. http://iphone-contacts.blogspot.com/#!/2012/02/iphone-contacts-apps.html

Answer (score -1):

Try these steps

1. export as vcard (using iBot)
2. Sign in to your iCloud account (if you don't have one, make one)
3. upload the vcard to your iCloud account
4. sign in to your iCloud on your phone and sync

Answer (score -2):

You can also try to check if your data shows up in your backup, using the iPhone Backup Extractor tool at iphonebackupextractor.com. Then you can try to recover it with this tool and importing back to your phone. Hope this helps.

Comment: Please review our site's [promotion guidelines](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion) and disclose if you are affiliated with the service you have linked to in all of your answers to date. The best way to promote here is to actively engage in many questions and not just ones relating to one product.